# How can I specify the start and end dates for SSIS SCD type 2 wizard instead of variables

Tags: ssis, scd

I'm trying to create a dimension table using SSIS but I'm having trouble creating an SCD type 2. I have a staging table with a business key column, a value column I want to track historical and start and end dates when changes occurred.

I am using the slowly changing dimension component in SSIS but the only date values I can write to the table is one of 3 variables (Container start time, system creation date or system start time). Is it possible to have the start and end date columns used instead?

Forgive me if this is a very basic question but SSIS is very very new to me.

Comment: I am hoping to have both the historical log and indications of current value and the number of changes

Comment: can you please detail your expected output ?